# Use jQuery UI buttons with jEditables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jeditable, jquery-ui-button

The question is, how do I make the buttons within jEditable elements jQuery UI buttons? Ideally, I want to call `$(':button').button()` after the jEditable form elements are loaded. Looking at the code, the 4 undocumented callback functions: `onedit`, `onsubmit`, `onreset`, `onerror` don't seem to be calling back at the right time.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

**EDIT**:

Here's the example code: http://jsfiddle.net/EU8ce/1/

I'd like the buttons in the editable element to be jQuery UI buttons.

Comment: Can you please post your code/fiddle so far?

Comment: @Nicola, please see the included jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a brief look at the jEditable source (I'm not really familiar with the plugin), the only hook (callback) that is useful in this case is the `onedit` which is called before the form is rendered. The plugin should really support `onbeforeedit` and `onafteredit` or something, for pre and post rendering. But it doesn't.

So you can add that functionality really easily. Or workaround it with a simple click handler:

http://jsfiddle.net/EU8ce/3/

Since you call `editable()` first, it'll bind the click handler first, so subsequent handlers will execute after, which has the effect of being a post-render callback, and you can execute your `button()` code there.

Comment: This is a wonderful solution for my problem. Thanks! I have this "why hadn't I thought of this" sort of feeling :)

Answer (score 2):

this might not be the cleanest thing in the world but it work: i created a custom type (which mirrors the standard type but calls button() on the buttons

```
$.editable.addInputType('example',{
    element : function(settings, original) {
                    var input = $('<input />');
                    if (settings.width  != 'none') { input.width(settings.width);  }
                    if (settings.height != 'none') { input.height(settings.height); }
                       input.attr('autocomplete','off');
                    $(this).append(input);
                    return(input);
                },

     buttons : function(settings, original) {
                    var form = this;
                    if (settings.submit) {
                        /* if given html string use that */
                        if (settings.submit.match(/>$/)) {
                            var submit = $(settings.submit).click(function() {
                                if (submit.attr("type") != "submit") {
                                    form.submit();
                                }
                            });
                        /* otherwise use button with given string as text */
                        } else {
                            var submit = $('<button type="submit" />').button();
                            submit.html(settings.submit);                            
                        }
                        $(this).append(submit);
                    }
                    if (settings.cancel) {
                        /* if given html string use that */
                        if (settings.cancel.match(/>$/)) {
                            var cancel = $(settings.cancel);
                        /* otherwise use button with given string as text */
                        } else {
                            var cancel = $('<button type="cancel" />').button();
                            cancel.html(settings.cancel);
                        }
                        $(this).append(cancel);

                        $(cancel).click(function(event) {
                            //original.reset();
                            if ($.isFunction($.editable.types[settings.type].reset)) {
                                var reset = $.editable.types[settings.type].reset;                                                                
                            } else {
                                var reset = $.editable.types['defaults'].reset;                                
                            }
                            reset.apply(form, [settings, original]);
                            return false;
                        });
                    }
                }

});
$("#edit").editable("someurl", {
    type: "example",
    submit: "OK",
    cancel: "Cancel"
});


$('#button').button();
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EU8ce/4/

Comment: thanks for this! It works, but slightly more code than I want to do :D